# How to save a dataframe after applyying lambda on one of its column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code that I wrote to modify one column of a data frame and when I save it as a CSV file it is saving the old data frame. How can I avoid this and save it as a new data frame?

```
df2 = df_new.loc[(df_new['channel_name'] == self.channel) & (df_new['subtype'] == 'chat'), ['text']]        
print(df2['text'])
df2['sentiment'] = df2.apply(lambda row: TextBlob(row['text']).sentiment.polarity, axis=1)
print(df2.head())
df2.to_csv("new.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

When I view the CSV file it does not have a `sentiment` column. How can I avoid that? With `print(df2.head())`

```
                                                    text  sentiment
17337  Hi <!channel> -- interesting business news is ...    0.16456
17338  <@U04JNBU9W>: <@U04JL900N> is already working ...    0.00000
```

I can view in the terminal that the data frame has a new column 'sentiment' with the modification applied. But when saving to CSV it is the original data frame.
The CSV file output

```
                                                    text     sentiment
17338   <@U04JNBU9W>: <@U04JL900N> is already working on it.    0.0
17339   Good news. This Chinese server is @ 120.39.251.37, by the way.  0.35
17340   Its good news. The task will continue to be part of the 2.0 project.    0.7
17341   good news, keep up the good work    0.7
```

Comment: Very strange, there should not be a discrepancy between the output of `head` and `to_csv`

Comment: Can you show how the TextBlob method would give the sentiment score of just one text?

Comment: was the csv file opened while saving the df2 to csv?

Comment: @MohitMotwani I edited the question with the output of `print(df2.head())` if that is what you are asking

Comment: @Jeril yeah there was a CSV file with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: can you delete the file and check whether a new file is being created there?

Comment: @Jeril yeah it was the old CSV file not being deleted that is causing the problem. But the format didn't look the same as with `df2.head()`.

Comment: are you saying that, still the column `sentiment` is not there in the saved csv

Comment: @Jeril There is But the contents of the CSV file are not organized in the same manner as `df2.head()` The sentiment values are not aligned as perfectly as the data frame. They are a little dispersed. Is it `sep='\t'` or the encoding not working?